# Deploy Struts2 WebApp Within An Eclipse RCP Application Via Jetty

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, jetty, eclipse-rcp

Now here's a mess for you...

I am currently working on an Eclipse RCP application plugin. The goal of this plugin is to serve up a webapp for users to interact with within an Eclipse ViewPart (SWT browser control).

I would like for this webapp to be powered by Struts2 and I already have Jetty at my disposal for serving things up.

Is there any way at all I can deploy a Struts2 WebApp in this way? If more info is needed please ask!

**EDIT #1:**

Some more detail. The only way I know how to deploy a struts2 application currently is via a war file (hosting on tomcat, that is). This is not something I can do in this case. I need to somehow deploy struts2 internally in an embedded way using the Jetty server provided with the Eclipse RCP framework.

**RESULT:**

As it turns out you can deploy a WAR file (struts2 app in this case) with embedded Jetty. I found Joakim Erdfelt doing it here: [Embedding Jetty as a Servlet Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246512/embedding-jetty-as-a-servlet-container)

Comment: It's very unclear how would you like to deploy it and what happened when you tried to do it. Also tell what did you try to better understand the issue.

Comment: @RomanC I made an edit to make my issue more clear. I have looked around for quite a while to find some pointers on how to do this with no luck before I asked here. I'm hoping someone out there has attempted this and could point me in the right direction. I just need to get Struts2 to deploy with the embedded Jetty server that is supplied with Eclipse RCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 web application can run in the servlet container like Jetty. Jetty also have an embedded option. Eclipse RCP uses Eclipse platform for extension and customization with plugins. There's an article of [using Eclipse RCP with embedded Jetty server](http://blog.firdau.si/2009/11/06/embedding-jetty-server-in-eclipse-rcp/):

> First, let’s add the jetty plugin to our dependencies. Open the tab
>   *Dependencies* in your plugin configuration. Then add these six
>   plugins to the *Required Plug-ins*:
>
> ```
> javax.servlet
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.regstry
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet
> org.mortbay.jetty.server
> org.mortbay.jetty.util
> ```
>
> In the list of plugins included at the launch of application you need
>   to change the *Auto-Start* value for three plugins to true (if you are
>   lazy, you can turn the default behavior to auto start but this is
>   another concern):
>
> ```
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.regstry
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet
> ```
>
> Now if you run the application you can check if your server is
>   correctly running by accessing `http://localhost`. This should work
>   flawlessly except maybe if you are not allowed to run server in port
>   80 or there is already a server running in port 80.
>
> You can change the port by adding an argument to the VM arguments in
>   *Run Configurations*. Add this value:
>   `-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.http.port=8888`. Change `8888` to
>   whatever port you want the server to be running.
>
> Now if you are running the application, you can access it from the
>   port you mentioned before.
>
> The next task is to define one (or several) servlet(s) that will serve
>   any request the server gets. To do this, you need to open the
>   *Extensions* tab from your plugin configuration and add a new
>   extension named `org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets`. After
>   that add new `servlet`. You need to mention the class name of the
>   servlet, and an alias for that. One note here is you need to add slash
>   in front of the alias. For example, if you want to make the servlet
>   accessible from `http://localhost:8888/webserviceInterface`, then the
>   alias value is `/webserviceInterface`. Of course, you need to
>   implement a servlet which will do the work you want.

Comment: This certainly pointed me in the right direction! Thank you! I did some more research after reading your post and also found this answer:
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246512/embedding-jetty-as-a-servlet-container

I suppose it is possible to just point Jetty to the WAR file and have it work that way!